# Textfields as search bar getting crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am using this code for textfiled as search bar.Here is my code. but i am getting crash for range on textfield.if i start entering then its crashing.Even not able to handle case sensitive text also

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "AFNetworking.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface ViewController ()
{
    NSMutableArray *countryArray;
    NSMutableArray *searchArray;
    NSString *searchTextString;
    BOOL isFilter;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _countryView.hidden = true;
    self->countryArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [self makeRestuarantsRequests];
    _tableView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
    _tableView.layer.borderWidth = 1;
    _tableView.layer.cornerRadius=5;
   [self.searchTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];

}


-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self
                                                   name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


#pragma mark - AFNetworking

-(void)makeRestuarantsRequests{

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"example url"];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];


    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                                                                        success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id responseObject) {
                                                                                            self->countryArray = [responseObject objectForKey:@"data"];
                                                                                                                                                                                    [self.tableView reloadData];
                                                                                        }
                                                                                        failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id responseObject) {
                                                                                            NSLog(@"Request Failed with Error: %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
                                                                                        }];
    [operation start];

}
#pragma mark - Tableview Delegate and Datasource

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{


    if(isFilter)
    {
        return [searchArray count];
    }
    else
        return  [countryArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


    NSDictionary *tempDictionary= [self->countryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    if(isFilter)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text=[searchArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else
    {
         cell.textLabel.text = [tempDictionary objectForKey:@"name"];
    }

//     cell.textLabel.text = [tempDictionary objectForKey:@"name"];

    return cell;
}


-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
   [_SelectCountryButton setTitle:cell.textLabel.text forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    _countryView.hidden = true;

}

-(void)textFieldDidChange:(UITextField *)textField
{
    searchTextString=textField.text;
    [self updateSearchArray:searchTextString];
}

-(void)updateSearchArray:(NSString *)searchText
{
    if(searchText.length==0)
    {
        isFilter=NO;
    }
    else{

        isFilter=YES;
        searchArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        for(NSString *string in countryArray){

            NSRange stringRange=[string rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
            if(stringRange.location !=NSNotFound){

                [searchArray addObject:string];
            }
        }
        [self.tableView reloadData];}
}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
#pragma mark UITextFieldDelegates


- (IBAction)SelectCountry:(id)sender {

    _countryView.hidden = false;

}



@end
```

Getting crash error :

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryI rangeOfString:options:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10128b4f0**

error code :

```
-(void)updateSearchArray:(NSString *)searchText
    {
        if(searchText.length==0)
        {
            isFilter=NO;
        }
        else{

            isFilter=YES;
            searchArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            for(NSString *string in countryArray){

                NSRange stringRange=[string rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
                if(stringRange.location !=NSNotFound){

                    [searchArray addObject:string];
                }
            }
            [self.tableView reloadData];}
    }
```

Please help me out.How can i solve this issues.
Thanks in advance !

UPDATE :

```
{"response":true,"message":"country.","data":[{"id":1,"name":"Afghanistan"},{"id":2,"name":"Albania"},{"id":3,"name":"Algeria"},{"id":4,"name":"American Samoa"},{"id":5,"name":"Andorra"},{"id":6,"name":"Angola"}]}
```

Comment: The error is saying that `string` in `for(NSString *string in countryArray)` is in fact a `NSDictionary` object, not a `NSString` one. Since you do `self->countryArray = [responseObject objectForKey:@"data"]`, my guess is that `[responseObject objectForKey:@"data"]` is an `NSArray` of `NSDictionary`.

Comment: so, how can i re change it to  make it wokr..i am totally confused

Comment: Show us the content of `[responseObject objectForKey:@"data"]`.

Comment: u measn , reponse data from server ?

Comment: That's what I mean, indeed. We can't help you if you don't show us what's the response and how to adapt your code.

Comment: @Larme  code updated, please check my post

Comment: Should have read more of your code, but it's still usefull. At some point you do `cell.textLabel.text = [tempDictionary objectForKey:@"name"];`, so you know that your array is made of `NSDictionary`. So `for(NSString *string in countryArray)` is wrong, it should be `for (NSDictionary *tempDict in countryArray) {NSString *string = tempDict objectForKey:@"name"]; //do the rest of your thing)}`

Comment: can u please give solution for `-(void)updateSearchArray:(NSString *)searchText` this method fully..i am confused wr to rplace it

Comment: yeah got it the issue

Comment: You'd also be better of starting something like this in Swift because that would prevent the problems like the one you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

well i have good approach with predicate

well according to you jsonResponse

```
 // so forEach loop should like this

 for(NSDictionary *Dic in CountryArray){
 NSString*str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dic objectForKey:@"name"]];
 }

  // well i am not using for each loop instead of that i have nsmutablearray name as  _searchArraySingle is same like your countryArray with predicate
 //  if you are using textfield in place of default Searchbar so use this then use NSPredicate 

 - (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 addObserver:self
 selector:@selector(textFieldTextDidChangeOneCI:)
 name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification
 object:searchTxt];
SearchBar.delegate = (id)self;

}


-(void)textFieldTextDidChangeOneCI:(NSNotification *)notification {
UITextField *textfield=[notification object];
[self predicatChangeText:textfield.text];
// NSLog(@"%@",textfield.text);

}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {

[textField resignFirstResponder];

return NO;
}

-(void)predicatChangeText:(NSString*)text{


 //   myJSON.array
 NSPredicate *predicateString = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K    contains[cd] %@", @"name", text];
_filteredArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[_searchArraySingle filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicateString]];

NSLog(@"_filteredArray=%lu",(unsigned long)[_filteredArray count]);

[self.tableView reloadData];

 }

 - (IBAction)cancleSearch:(id)sender {
searchTxt.text=@"";
if (_filteredArray) {
    _filteredArray=nil;
  }

 [self.searchTxt resignFirstResponder];
_filteredArray = myJSON.array;
[self.tableView reloadData];
 }
```

Might this will help you out !!!! GoodLuck